# Exterior Cement Patio poured all the way to exterior brick of the house. Water proofing options?

Tags: water, waterproofing, brick, patio, cement

My house was built in 1955, at some point (unknown) a cement patio was poured beside the house. The cement was poured all the way to the brick work of the house (No visible gap or nor is there a good slope away from the brick). I have a concern that this keeps the wall moist and I am looking for options on how to fix this. (I don't know of any water penetration, but it is a concern). The brick work is obviously old (1955) and some bricks appear to have some damage possibly due to freezing moisture. I am looking for what options I have. Last year I used Ghostshield on the brick but I am looking for additional suggestions. This is the North facing side of the house so I get moss and stains easily as it doesn't receive full sun. I am power washing the patio today and will be looking for possible products to use on it after it's clean.

This is a cement patio, The brushed cement pad directly touches the bottom edge of the brick of the house. It does not appear that any brick are below the cement pad, So it appears the cement pad is mostly in contact with the cinderblock foundation.

Comment: Can you please verify that it is indeed brick rather than CMU (concrete masonry unit aka cinder block)?

Answer (score 0):

Flaking of the face bricks, caused by dampness in the outer layer of the brick freezing and expanding when the moisture melts is common - especially with cheaper bricks.

You should have a damp proof course - and the patio really ought not to have bridged it. One can be injected into the brick, for a price.

Provided the internal side of the wall is **never** damp, its probably OK.
But I would get a professional damp surveyor to look at it.